# What to think of a missing man?

Tags: debian, man

I'm trying to get info on `mktemp`.

`MKTEMP(1)` contains these two lines:

```
SEE ALSO
       mkstemp(3), mkdtemp(3), mktemp(3)
```

Ok, let's see.

```
tomasz@E4200:~$ man 3 mkstemp
No manual entry for mkstemp in section 3
tomasz@E4200:~$ man 3 mkdtemp
No manual entry for mkdtemp in section 3
tomasz@E4200:~$ man 3 mktemp
No manual entry for mktemp in section 3
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

I didn't know this is possible. Do I need to install them separately? What's the best way? Is this a release bug?

Comment: Try `find /usr -name "mktemp.3*"`.

Comment: What's this supposed to do?

Comment: That would have searched `/usr` for the missing `man page` in case you already have it.

Comment: That would be even better than it was. Does that happen?

Comment: Since your `MANPATH` is not set, it may be installed in a different folder. Just run my `find` command to see if it finds it and report back what it finds.

Comment: Well, now I've followed the accepted answer and I'm sure I have them. And can call them with `man`. So it's a bit too late, I gather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search for the debian package that contains those extra development man pages (should be `manpages-dev`) and install it.

It is quite common nowadays for distributions to not install development manpages by default.

You can use `apt-file search` to search for other missing man pages.

Comment: It's only "common" for Debian (and derived things such as Ubuntu) due to licensing disagreements.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, do you have a link? Fedora also doesn't install the `man-pages` package when doing a minimal install (or one that doesn't depend on the 'Standard' package group). Similar situation with CentOS.